# C pthread_join return value

Tags: c, return, pthreads

I'm attempting to print a return value from pthread_join. I have the following code:

```
    for(j = 0 ; j < i ; ++j){
        pthread_join( tid[j], returnValue);  /* BLOCK */
        printf("%d\n",  (int)&&returnValue);
}
```

All of the threads are stored in the tid array and are created and returned correctly. At the end of each thread function I have the following line:

```
pthread_exit((void *)buf.st_size);
```

I am attempting to return the size of some file I was reading. For some reason I cannot get it to print the correct value. It is more then likely the way I am attempting to dereference the void ** from the pthread_join function call, but I'm not too sure how to go about doing that.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to pass the address of a `void *` variable to `pthread_join` -- it will get filled in with the exit value.  That `void *` then should be cast back to whatever type was originally stored into it by the `pthread_exit` call:

```
for(j = 0 ; j < i ; ++j) {
    void *returnValue;
    pthread_join( tid[j], &returnValue);  /* BLOCK */
    printf("%zd\n",  (size_t)(off_t)returnValue);
}
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, the only issue I have now is the warning I receive when I compile it, "warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]", other than that it works as I need it to.

Comment: Use `intptr_t` instead of `int` to get an integer type that's the same size as a pointer.

Comment: The last line should be `printf("%d\n",  *(int *)returnValue);`

Comment: @smac89: No, that would likely crash -- the exit value is a `off_t` that has been cast to a `void *`, so you need to cast it back to an integral type, not try to dereference the invalid pointer.

Answer (score 0):

This is working:

```
for(j = 0 ; j < i ; ++j) {
    int returnValue;
    pthread_join( tid[j], (void **)&returnValue);  /* BLOCK */
    printf("%d\n",  returnValue);
}
```

Comment: If `sizeof(int) < sizeof(void *)`, this will clobber whatever is in the stack frame after `returnValue`.  It will also ony "work" on little-endian machines.